# How to prevent my guest user from installing chrome extensions

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, guest-account

In my home PC, I have two logins. One is mine and another is a guest user.

Is there any way to restrict my guest user from installation of Chrome extensions? I fear installation of malicious extensions in Chrome, is there any way to prevent this?

I tried to create one user in Chrome and can't find any option to block installation of Chrome extensions.

I'm using Windows 8 32-bit

Comment: why dont install a software like reboot restore rx for guest user so that every time system reboots , it resets to the baseline version regardless of the changes the guest user makes.

Comment: Is Chrome not installed "per user" in the user-folder as default? So your Chrome does not effect his (or the other way around). So all you need to do is figure a way to disable installation of extension in Chrome (in general) and set this only for the guest account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like i stated in my comment Chrome is installed on a "per user" basis so extensions added to a guest installation of Chrome will have no effect on your own.

But if you really want to restrict a user to not be able to install extensions you can revoke the rights to write (and possibly read) in the following directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

For the guest account that would be:

```
C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Go to the `Default`-directory for the guest, Right-click `Extensions` and choose `Properties`. Click the `Security`-tab and click <kbd>Edit</kbd>. Click on the Guest-account and check the `Deny` after "Full-control" and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You might want to take ownership of this directory too because clever guests can change the rights back (because they still own the directory and if you take ownership they can't). Although clever guest might just install a new version of Chrome to a different directory again so it depends on how smart your guests are.

[image: Guest]

They get:

[image: denied1]

[image: denied2]